# Compare the area of two different catenoids spanned by the same two circles

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality, area, minimal-surfaces

A catenoid is obtained by rotating the graph of the function $f(x)=a \cosh (x/a)$ around the $x$-axis.

Consider catenoids that satisfy the boundary condition $f(c)=f(-c)=r>0$. We have $a\cosh(c/a)=r$, and hence
$$
\cosh (c/a)=(c/a)(r/c),
$$
so there exists a number $R_0>0$, such that when $r/c>R_0$, there are exactly two catenoids spanned by the two coaxial circles with the same radius $r$.

My question is: **which one of the two catenoids has larger surface area?** This seems to be much more difficult than it appears to be. Indeed, I can compute the area explicitly:
$$\pi a (a\sinh (2c/a)+2c)
$$
but the two values of $a$ are very hard to characterise, so I find it very difficult to compare the areas.

See [this link](http://curvasysuperficies.blogspot.com/2017/05/surfaces-of-revolution-with-constant_10.html) for a diagram of the two catenoids.

Comment: It may be of interest to provide a figure such as the last one in [this document](http://curvasysuperficies.blogspot.com/2017/05/surfaces-of-revolution-with-constant_10.html) in order to understand how are the two catenoids. More generaly, you should mention one or two meaningful references for your study in order that the potential answerers don't have to rebuild all out of scratch. See as well [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurfaceofRevolution.html).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the link. My question is not motivated by a particular book/paper, though. I come up with it from scratch. I am now looking for references as well.

Comment: For another question, after having "worked from scratch" for a while, it is essential to browse potential litterature before asking ; very often, one finds the answer in this way. It is so easy with Google ! The issue sometimes is to find the **good keywords** (the first ones may not be the good ones, but by "rebounding", at last, one finds the good ones. Here, I have used "catenoid spanned two parallel circles critical", and I have got many documents, for example this (new) one https://www.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01120475/document.